# Make three tabs fill width of container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make three "tabs" fill the entire width of a larger container div, but the width always falls a few pixels short, or if I increase the width of the tabs, the last is pushed onto a lower level. Also, would `li` elements be more appropriate for building these tabs? I'm using bootstrap if so if you know of a built-in solution it has, I'm very willing to go for that.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/tadekeyi/2/edit)

```
<!--HTML-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="vendor_container"> 
<div class="vendor_header">
  <span>
     Company
  </span>
</div>

<div class="vendor_tabs">  
  <div class="vendor_tab vendor_contacts">
    Contacts
  </div>
  <div class="vendor_tab vendor_clients">
    Clients
  </div>
  <div class="vendor_tab vendor_notes">
    Notes  
  </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
</div>  
<div class="vendor_pane vendor_contacts">
  <table class="detail_table contacts">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>
              Name
           </th>
           <th>
              email
           </td>
           <th>
              Phone
           </th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>
              Dave Sample
           </td>
           <td>
              dsample@sample.com
           </td>
           <td>
              555.123.1234
           </td>
           <td>
              <a href="#" class="edit_contact">
              Edit
              </a>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
              Jill Sample
           </td>
           <td>
              jsample@sample.com
           </td>
           <td>
              555.123.1234
           </td>
           <td>
              <a href="#" class="edit_contact">
              Edit
              </a>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
              Irene Sample
           </td>
           <td>
              isample@sample.com
           </td>
           <td>
              555.123.1234
           </td>
           <td>
              <a href="#" class="edit_contact">
              Edit
              </a>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>  

</div>

<div class="vendor_pane vendor_contacts">
  <table class="detail_table vendor_clients">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>
              Client
           </th>
           <th>
              ID
           </th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>
              Sample 1
           </td>
           <td>
              1234
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
              sample 2
           </td>
           <td>
              9874
           </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>  
</div>  

<div class="vendor_pane vendor_notes">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

/*CSS*/

```
body{
  margin:5px;
}
.vendor_container{
  width: 100%;
  max-width:1040px;
}
.vendor_header{

}
.vendor_header, .vendor_tab, th{
  text-align:center;
}
.vendor_tab{
  float:left;
  width:33%;
  padding: 5px 0 12px;
  border-color: gray;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px 1px 0 0;
}
.vendor_tab:first-of-type{
  border-left-width:1px;
}
.border_left{
  border-left-width: 1px;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
.vendor_pane ~.vendor_pane{
  display:none;
}
.vendor_pane table{
  width:100%;
}
.vendor_pane{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML & CSS

Comment: @Paulie_D he included a JSBIN

Comment: Which is all very well but not what is required by SO standards since that link could disappear or be updated.

Comment: @Paulie_D updated: now SO standards compliant.

Comment: @whoever Why would this need to be closed?

Comment: @Paulie_D surely the sheer size of this content is almost LESS helpful

Comment: Hey...I;m just saying what is the SO norm. If his post is to be of use to future users the HTML & CSS should be included in the post. - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Would it be worth encouraging a more 'condensed' version of the code too and perhaps screenshots then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap includes a "justified" option under the `nav-tabs` section.

Have a look at the documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified). However, if you'd prefer to just use their `CSS`.

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.vendor_tab{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
    padding: 5px 0 12px;
    border-color: gray;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px 1px 0 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/As9H7/2/)

PS. [tabified your HTML](http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your tabs are set to 33%, 3*33% =99% not 100%, the gap you see is the remaining 1%.

To fix the width issue change:

```
.vendor_pane {
  width: 99%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Alternatively, make your tab widths 33.33..%, although this may introduce rendering nuances.

You should also set `box-sizing:border-box` on `.vendor-tab` so they dont move onto two lines on smaller widths.

Comment: @thomas You didnt add box-sizing